# Image Collection containing orbits not related to the defined boundary

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I tried to download all the images in ImageCollection for methane emission (in a specific timeframe and for a defined location)and check their orbits. Even though I've added filterBounds, there are images in the list that are not related to the defined geometry. This is the code:

```
var Oklahoma_roi = STATES.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME','Oklahoma'));
Map.addLayer(Oklahoma_roi,['green'],'Oklahoma');
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4")
              .select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air')
              .filterDate('2023-07-17','2023-07-18')
              .filterBounds(Oklahoma_roi);

var temp = dataset.map(function(img) {
  var gain = img.get("ORBIT");
  return(img)
});
print(temp.aggregate_array('ORBIT'))
```

and here is the result:[image]

Comparing the results with Sentinel 5p open source, some of the orbits in the list do not cover the required area. I've tried this matter for different timeframes. But there was no change.

[image]

Can you help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The bounds on all S5P images are global, so the filterBounds does nothing. Essentially, the footprints are sufficiently complex that no attempt was made to represent them.

You can get rid of images that don't intersect your region by doing a mapped reduceRegion on each image using your ROI and counting the number of intersecting pixels; if it's 0, discard the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please guide me on how  I can do mapped reduceRegion on each image? Can I do it on Javascript, or do I need to process the images after downloading them?